# Blazor app accesing multiple downstream APIs

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, webassembly

What I'm trying to do is to access Graph as well as another downstream API from Blazor Wasm app, I've gave the client app registration permissions to both Graph and Server App registration.

I have not been able to make Blazor switch the authorization schema between Graph and my API.

When I try to call my downstream api, the resulting token in header is the one belonging to Graph which is the only one who works, obviously it returns a invalid signature error.

Any lead to guide me thru the right thing to do in this case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why manually switch back and forth instead of creating and injecting dedicated HTTP Client services corresponding to each API requiring different configuration of any kind? I'm sure there's another way to get it to work but it would seem much cleaner and more maintainable to use discrete http services.

Comment: I have dedicated client services,  each with his own AuthenticationServiceHandler which seems like is not working correctly since this is the one in charge to get the token for HttpClient

Comment: Do you have any update on it? pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> access Graph as well as another downstream API from Blazor Wasm app

I assume you'd finished the code to call graph api, and you may already used the graph SDK or generate access token manually then send http request with the token. So you must set the api scope for it. And this is what I want to say, different API used different scope, and we can only set one type of API in one time. That's say, when we want to call MS graph api, we need to set the scope like `User.Read`, but if you want to call some other custom API which is protected by Azure AD, then the api should look like `api://xxxxx/User.Read`. This is [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) about how to protect API with AAD.

This is what I did in my side, first, creating a blazor wsam project with the Microsoft identity platform, this will help to build the template.

[image]

Then I need to have an Azure AD app which I think you already had it, update the variables in `appsetting.json.

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
    "ClientId": "Azure_ad_app_id",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
```

Then I have the sign in module and we are able to sign in with microsoft account. I need to add the graph SDK into my project. Following [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/blazorwasm-calls-MS-graph) to add `UserProfile.razor, UserProfileBase.cs, GraphClientExtensions.cs` and modify `Program.cs`

[image]

Now, I can call graph API to get user profile. But since the api scope is `User.Read` now, it can't be used for another API. I created a webapi project in the same solution and followed the tutorial above which makes the API required a correct bearer token in the request header and added CORS policy for it.

Then in `UserProfile.razor` page, I [modify the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0#request-additional-access-tokens) like below to call the web api it worked for me.

```
@page "/profile"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits UserProfileBase
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider

<h3>User Profile</h3>
<button @onclick="call">
    call api
</button>
<div>@result</div>
@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> DisplayName </td>
            <td> @_user.DisplayName </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> UserPrincipalName </td>
            <td> @_user.UserPrincipalName </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

@code {

    private string result = "no data now";

    private async Task call()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        //http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7018/WeatherForecast");

        var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
            new AccessTokenRequestOptions
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { "api://aad_client_id_that_exposed_api/Tiny.Read" }
                });

        if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",
                $"Bearer {token.Value}");
            result = await http.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7018/WeatherForecast");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as I have some time, thanks for taking the time to reply.